# Visual Basic for totaling up each column in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

How do I total up the cells in a column in Excel using VBA?
For example, there are three columns, each named as Lane 1,2 and 3.
In Lane 1, there are 10 cells representing 10 cars.
How do I program the software to tell me that there are 10 cars in Lane 1?

Comment: See [ask] and provide more relevant details.

Answer (score 1):

With a simple loop (for/while, you choose) that for each column counts the cells you want to (non-empty, empty, with some text, etc.).
You can also put the data in an array (for example 3x10 - where 3 is the number of lanes and 10 is the maximum length of a lane) to use it in any way you want.

I won't write any code. You have to show some effort.

Comment: My apologises, I am a new learner in VBA. I am wondering if there is any suggestions where beginners can learn VBA fast and effectively? Thanks for the swift response.

Comment: I think Stackoverflow is a good website, but you want to consider searching here and on Google your question, find some pieces of code and understand what they mean, then try to shape them to meet your needs. The Macro-Recorder in Excel can also be of some help. You can of course post your code here and kindly ask for help in case it doesn't work. Please see the link MP24 provided to understand better how to ask a question.